# Download .doc that comes from a Java REST API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, save-as, rest

The problem is that when receiving the ResponseEntity  from angular java, it receives it as Blob, but the Word it downloads is not correct, it is a word with the path where the correct File is

```
    private aFile() {
    this.rest.aFile(this.formData)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.contenidoFile = res;

        var blob = new Blob([this.contenidoFile], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

     saveAs(blob, "createdocument.doc");

      }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        alert('Ha habido un error');
      });
  }

 aFile(formData: FormData) {
    return this.http.post(PATH_FILE, formData, {
      responseType:'blob'
    });
  }
```

The code in Java:

```
 @PostMapping("/file")
    public ResponseEntity<File> docFileV1(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile originalFile) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(docService.processDocFile(originalDocFile));

    }
```

The text of the original Word for example would be "Hello how is this a word document", instead the text of the Word document that angular downloads is
"C:\var\tmp\DocWork\bcc272d8-fdac-4384-97bc-1fdc5dd5736b\document.doc"

In other words, the path where the word I want to download is converted into word, how can I download the original word instead of its path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as follow, i test it with .net core backend

is console.log print response properties like 'response.body'?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(url: string) { 

    const formData = {};
    return this.download(url, formData)
      .subscribe((response) => {

        console.log(response);

        let file = new Blob([response.body], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"});

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          const name = "test";
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, name);
        } else {
          const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          const child = window.open(fileUrl);
        }
      });
  }

  download(url: string, formData): Observable<any> {
    const requestOptions : any = {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",           
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          "Accept": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        })
    };
    const request = new Request(requestOptions);
    return this.http.post(url, formData, requestOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for downloading file instead of using **saveAs**:

```
 var blob = new Blob([this.contenidoFile], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
const e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
      a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "data.docx";
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ["application/octet-stream", a.download, a.href].join(":");
    e.initEvent("click", true, false);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: This did not work for me, the saveAs saved well, the wrong is the contentFile that returns the url instead of the File

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: i am using chrome